# conversion of dictionary to json to be sent to requests.post

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a data frame like this.

`df=pd.DataFrame({'sub1':[10,20,30,40],'sub2':[5,10,15,20],'sub3':[1,2,3,4]}.`
and a dictionary like this.

```
stud={}
stud['name']="abc"
stud['id'] ="AB10"
stud['address']="some_address"
```

I convert that data frame to dictionary and combine with the stud dictionary.I wrote the following code.Then this stud dictionary should be made in a json format and sent as a web service.

```
stud={}
stud['name']="abc"
stud['id'] ="AB10"
stud['address']="some_address"
for i in range(0,len(df)):
   data_sample={}
   data_sample_row=df.iloc[i]
   a=data_sample_row.to_dict()
   stud['data_sample']=a
   str_details=str(stud)
```

I would like to get the result as shown below.

```
"{'name':'abc','id':'AB10','address':'some_address','data_sample':{'sub1':10,'sub2':5,'sub3':1}}"
"{'name':'abc','id':'AB10','address':'some_address','data_sample':{'sub1':20,'sub2':10,'sub3':2}}"
"{'name':'abc','id':'AB10','address':'some_address','data_sample':{'sub1':30,'sub2':15,'sub3': 3}}"
"{'name':'abc','id':'AB10','address':'some_address','data_sample':{'sub1': 40,'sub2':20,'sub3': 4}}"
```

I would like to send this as a parameter in requests.post as following.

```
response=requests.post(url="some_url",data=str_details)
```

If I don't convert to string, gives me an error, JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1) If I pass json=str_details, as argument gives me the same error, How to resolve this and get the desired results.

Comment: Please post your stacktrace (full error text). This will allows us to find your problem faster.

Comment: You should be able to post without calling `str` on your dictionary, i.e., `requests.post(url, json=stud)`. See https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

Comment: Have you tried printing `stud` and `str_details` to see what the data looks like? I see this type of question all of the time and as soon as I print the problem container it is completely obvious what the problem is. Also, in your example you didn't close the parens for `Dataframe`. Does that error exist in your code?